# Get users which have multiple entries in multiple categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query returns no results, I'm guessing because I'm 'and'ing twice in a row on the same value.  If I change it to 'or', then I get 2/3rds of what I need but I need users that have multiple entries in multiple categories - is there a way to effectively say "give me the users who have count greater than 1 in category A *AND* category B" in SQL?

```
SELECT TOP (20) UserId     
FROM PaymentRecord pr
inner join Transactions t on t.Entity = pr.UserId
where t.Category = 'CardSwipe' and t.Category = 'EFT'
group by pr.UserId
having count(t.CreatedAt) > 1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select top (20) t.Entity as UserId
from Transactions t
where t.Category in ( 'CardSwipe',  'EFT')
group by t.Entity
having count(distinct t.Category) = 2;
```

As you have written the query, the `Users` table is not necessary -- unless there are "entities" in transactions that are not users, so the `join` is for filtering.